# How to get all the group names in given subscription az cli

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I am trying to iterate over all the group names in given Azure subscription:

```sh
az group list --subscription XXX --query "{Name:id}"
```

This produces an array with elements in the following format: `/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/NAME`, which basically is the id of the resource group.

For each of these elements I want to select and extract just the `NAME`. I tried to split based on "/" delimiter but it did not work. Has anyone faced similar use-case before and how did you extract just the group name from the id.

Comment: `az group list --subscription XXX --query "{Name:id}" | awk -F"/" { print $NF }`

Comment: these linux folks always try to use awk... you can just do: `az group list --query "[].name" -o tsv`